# How to use a Surface pro as a microphone for my desktop?

Tags: windows, desktop-computer, microphone, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

I'm currently using my Surface pro 4 as a second screen by using the connect to a wireless display functionality, is it possible to also use it as a microphone?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to connect the audio output (higher than microphone level) to the microphone input of the other device. I think you might be able to do it, but it may not be worth the effort.

You would have to attenuate and then balance the audio output because microphone input is measured in millivolts.

An inexpensive microphone would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but it would involve to connect the headphone output to the line input (not mic input) of the PC using a jack connector (mono to mono or mono to stereo?).

Plus you can route the signal using the Windows software Cable.

A headset might serve you better (but that wasn't what you were asking).